Sharing SQLAlchemy models between flask and non-flask python projects
We have 2 projects - Project_A and Project_B. Project_A does data processing, saves processing results to a database, generates an .sql dump and uploads it to cloud storage. Project_B is a flask app, it downloads the .sql dump from the cloud storage, loads it up into its own database and it has endpoints through which the data can be accessed.
Both projects' databases have the same table and column structure, relationships, etc., which means both projects have models files which have to be synchronized. We decided to move the models files to a submodule - Project_Shared, so that we have to make changes to the models only in one place. This is where we were met by a roadblock.
Project_A uses SQLAlchemy with declarative_base and Project_B uses flask-sqlalchemy with db.Model in their own respective models classes. This is an example of a difference in one of the model classes:
In Project_A we have:
class ProcessingModel1(Base):
 name = sa.Column(...)

In Project_B we have:
class ProcessingModel1(db.Model):
 name = sa.Column(...)

What is the way to go about this situation? Creating a declarative_base in the submodule, initializing the flask app's database with the same declarative_base and making all references point to the submodule models? Would Inheriting the fields from the submodule model classes in the flask app work?

You can tell Flask-SQLAlchemy to use your declarative Base as the model base, like this:
from sqlalchemy import orm
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Base = orm.declarative_base()

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)

See the docs here and elsewhere.
